# Plausible scenario for Prolog or any other logical programing language

Tags: animation, 3d, prolog, declarative

As someone who does computer animation, is the following scenario plausible in Prolog or any other logical programing language:

Let us say I create a scene with a 3D model dog, with a rig that has full character physics and controls, and I made an environment for the dog. Now let us say I include all the variables and algorithms for all the objects and physics in the scene as Atoms and Rules in Prolog (or what ever language). Now let us say I give the goal that I want my dog to get from point A to point B in my environment.  Would logical programing, taking in all the data into account, animate the walking from point a to b, even though as the animator, I never animated the dog walking, just provided all the info and martial's that would require a dog to walk?

Answer (score 4):

I work with animation, and program in Prolog.

Prolog's a Turing complete language, so anything that can be programmed can be programmed in Prolog.

But....

Your question assumes that you have a 'full character physics and controls' - that means a psychophysiokinesiologic model of the dog. You'd have to have complete models of the dog's muscles, nervous system, and brain. That's not really possible (for one thing, we don't have a good enough model of the canine brain, and probably don't have enough knowledge of canine kinesiology).

Now, if you mean 'I want to give it a walk cycle, and have the motion generated', then yes, that's pretty do-able. Cogbot (http://code.google.com/p/opensim4opencog/) does this for bipeds in the OpenSim virtual world system using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Well i don't nessarly think you need everything, just enough. Consider something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCXzcPNsqGA, where genetic programming creates 3d models and animations that are created when an "evolutionary alrgoritum" reaches (or gets close to reaching) the goal (fitness function).
I'm woundering if the same can be done with logical programmin..that is, provide the "parts" and  goal, and let the computer figure out how to best reach the goal.

Comment: For instance, couldn't you just say "i am a polygon model, I have collision detection to the ground, I have gravity effecting my rig system, and friction to the ground.  I have joints that I am allowed to rotate. I am currently at this X,Y,Z position and my goal is to get to this X,Y,Z position at this time. Now what values for each joint would I need as the clock ticks for me to get to position A to position B?

Comment: Why would that produce realistic motion? Dogs walk like dogs because they have doggie motor control programs.  Anyway, yes, Prolog's a decent choice, not because it's based on logic, but because it's friendly to constraint systems.